# Why un-like a discussion board list will not decrease the Like count for the discussion item in sharepoint on-premises 2013

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-on-prem, discussion-board, rating

I have added a discussion board list inside our team site. now i login as a test user where i Like an existing article to test if the Like functionality will be available to users with Read permission. and it worked. so after that i unlike the discussion board item, but the like count did not decrease. so currently the discussion board list have a Like count =1 , but no one have like it!!
I try to fix this, where i re-like the discussion board item, so that the like count will be consistent with the users who like it,, but now the like count have increased to 2 and only one user have like it!! so is there a way to fix this? or a way to reset the like count = 0?